# Subtle gradient strokes

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm here today because I have a question on how I can achieve something similar to the subtle gradient effect in the image below. I've looked through their HTML & CSS and I personally can't see how they've done it. I've then tried to search Google but no luck.

[Subtle gradient effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFHs2.png)

If anyone is able to help me out, that would be amazing!

I've tried to give an SVG of a similar shape a gradient but struggled.

Comment: Have you experimented with CSS radial-gradient()?

Comment: I highly recomend you take a tutorial on how to use the developer console (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/), this way everytime you find an interesting effect that catch your attention you can open the developer tools and see how they did it. Not specific to your question but learning this goes a loong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty same effect by [Tim Wilson](https://x.com/actualTimWilson) on this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/TWilson/pen/jOdWqbZ). It's just a simple looped animation with some nice gradients:

```
@keyframes jumbo {
from {
    background-position: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
}
to {
    background-position: 350% 50%, 350% 50%;
}
```

He cuts off bottom of the gradients with a gradient mask:

```
 mask-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at 100% 0%, black 40%, transparent 70%);
```

Don't forget to toggle dark mode ;)